# Ionic Modal hide not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to somehow show or hide a modal using Ionic.

I would like when the user calls the submit, and the inputs after processing are accepted, then the modal should close. In case the inputs are rejected then show again the modal along with a message.

My issue here is that I managed to make .show(); work but .hide(); is not. Any ideas why Im facing this issue?

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $http, $ionicModal) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.change = function() {
   // Do Stuff here

      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
          scope: $scope,
          animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.modal = modal;
      });

      if ($localStorage.value == true) {
        console.log("Modal will pop up");
        $scope.modal.show(); //it works
      }
      else{
        console.log("Unregistered device");
      }

    console.log($localStorage.value);
  }

    $scope.submit = function(){
      var link = 'http://example.com/api.php';

      //HERE I TRIED TO DECLARE THE MODAL AGAIN JUST IN CASE IT WORKS BUT NO LUCK
      //$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
      //    scope: $scope,
      //    animation: 'slide-in-up'
      //}).then(function(modal) {
      //    $scope.modal = modal;
      //});

      $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username, password: $scope.data.password}).then(function (res){
          $scope.response = res.data;
          $localStorage.token = res.data;
          console.log($localStorage.token);
          $scope.modal.hide(); //Not working
      });
    };


});
```

Update:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $http, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
 $scope.data = {};

 $scope.change = function() {
  $localStorage.value = !$localStorage.value;
  $scope.value = $localStorage.value;

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  if ($localStorage.value == true) {
   console.log("Modal will pop up");
   $scope.modal.show();
   setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
   }, 5000);
  } else {
   console.log("Unregister device");
  }

  console.log($localStorage.value);
 }

 $scope.submit = function() {
  var link = 'http://app.example.com/api.php';

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $http.post(link, {
    username: $scope.data.username,
    password: $scope.data.password
   }).then(function(res) {
    $scope.response = res.data;
    $localStorage.token = res.data;
    console.log($localStorage.token);
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
   })
   .finally(function() {
    $scope.modal.hide(); // this will execute no matter what happens with the http call!
    console.log("Finally Function");
   });
 };
});
```

[image: Demo of the issue]

Comment: Are you able to see any error on debug mode?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: Could you put a console.log below var=link but above $http.post and see it fire on submit? I suspect your $scope.submit function isn't firing, hence why $scope.modal.hide isn't firing either. To get a grasp of whether or not it's your code, try a quick test in $scope.change where the modal shows and then hides/destroys itself.

Comment: it does because I see >console.log($localStorage.token);

Comment: I also add : setTimeout(function() {
          $scope.modal.hide();
      }, 5000);   to the $scope.change but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how and why but this code here solved the issue. I can now use .show(), .hide() functions without any problems. If you've got any ideas why, please feel free to share your thoughts.

```
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  }, {
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    focusFirstInput: true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine exactly where the error is because we can't debug the http call BUT it is much better practice to attach a finally() handler to the end of your promise chain so that it closes.

The issue is that if the http call fails (which it is bound to do since you can lose a network/signal at any time), your modal will never close. Closing it in the finally guarantees that it will close, whether the http call is successful or not.

You may want to handle the failure by doing something else like displaying some kind of message to the user saying that the server couldn't be contacted, etc but here is a little snippet of what could help the scenario.

```
$http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username, password: $scope.data.password})
.then(function (res){
    $scope.response = res.data;
    $localStorage.token = res.data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
})
.finally(function () {
    $scope.modal.hide(); // this will execute no matter what happens with the http call!
});
```

Comment: You sir just gave a buffet of food for thought! :) I'll give it a try and I'll let you know

Comment: I tried your way but the issue it seems to be the .hide(); as you can see the console.log(); works, so the .finally function is called. What is really strange is that I dont get any kind of errors. that line is just skipped.

Comment: Have a look on the 1st question for the update along with a gif showing the function in action.